# Deferred deep linking through 3rd party App Store like HockeyApp?

Tags: ios, app-store, deep-linking, branch.io, hockeyapp

I am currently working on an iOS app that I first plan on releasing through HockeyApp (eventually I plan to move it to the iOS app store). I want to do deferred deep linking with my app using branch. Is it possible to do deep linking (to install the app - for users that don't have it) through HockeyApp or does it have to be done through the iOS app store?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you click the Branch Link and are redirected to the App Store, you can still defer deep link through HockeyApp as long as the Branch SDK is integrated.